# Stream sorted() leads to unexpected results

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

I have an Array and a Stream like below.

```
String[] names = {"Alex", "Anna", "Abhi", "Some", "Broad", "Dustin", 
                  "amanda", "Hanna", "Steve", "Sydney"};
        
Stream.of(names)
        .sorted()
        .map(String::toLowerCase)
        .filter(x -> x.startsWith("a"))
        .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
        //I have also tried - .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Actual Output:

```
abhi
alex
anna
amanda
```

Expected Output:

```
abhi
alex
amanda
anna
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are first sorting and only then applying the `toLowerCase` on the elements, and since `Anna` has capital `A` will come before `amanda`.

Do the following instead:

```
Stream.of(names)
        .map(String::toLowerCase)
        .filter(x -> x.startsWith("a"))
        .sorted()
        .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
abhi
alex
amanda
anna
```

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the `.sorted()` call before [`forEachOrdered`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEachOrdered-java.util.function.Consumer-), otherwise the contents of the stream will not be sorted after applying `.toLowerCase()`.

What `forEachOrdered` does is run a function on every item in the stream *in the order that they are in the stream*; it does not sort the values themselves.

Comment: So basically the `.sorted()` is in the wrong place in the call chain, and therefore will have no effect?

Comment: @RobertHarvey It has an effect, but not the desired one, since it sorts uppercase letters before lowercase letters.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It does have an effect, but as dreamcash's answer states, the capital letter 'A' in 'Anna' comes before the lowercase 'a' in 'amanda'. The `.sorted()` call needs to come after `.toLowerCase()` to be correct.

Comment: Not sure which answer to accept as you and dreamcrash answered at the same time.

Comment: @AjayKumar Go for dreamcash's answer: theirs explains why `.sorted()` doesn't work as expected.